# Visual Studio Load Testing - Which post web test event handler to use

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, event-handling, load-testing

I have a static object in my test class that gets populated through a load test plugin, and needs to be updated with data that comes back from each request. The only piece of information I need besides the response data is the WebTestUserId from the original webtest context that was used when the request was sent.

I can do this through a validation rule it seems:

```
ValidationClass: ValidationRule
{
    public override void Validate(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        JObject responseBody = JObject.Parse(e.Response.BodyString);           
        int webTestUserId= ((TheTestClass)sender).Context.WebTestUserId;

        // update some static field in the test class
    }
}
```

However I do see other options that could potentially work, but am having trouble finding documentation on the differences or recommended approach. I see the event handlers:

> [WebTest.PostWebTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.webtesting.webtest.postwebtest.aspx), 
>   WebTest.ValidateResponse,
>   WebTest.ValidateResponseOnPageComplete, and 
>   [LoadTest.TestFinished](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.loadtesting.loadtest.testfinished.aspx) (would be used in the plugin)

I cannot post more than 2 links but the two event handlers not hyperlinked can be found on the WebTest class.

In what situations should each of these be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Validation rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182556%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) are intended to check that the test is running correctly and to set a failure status and failure message, if appropriate. For your purposes it may be better to use a plugin to retrieve and save the wanted data. If the data comes from a specific request then use the `PostRequest` method of a [`WebTestRequestPlugin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514192(v=vs.110).aspx). If data needs to be collected from all requests then use the `PostRequest` method of a [`WebTestPlugin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243191(v=vs.110).aspx).

There is overlap between the functions of the different plugin (also extraction and validation rule) types. Their purpose should be clear from the Microsoft documentation. The web test items are only called from the web tests that explicitly invoke them. The `TestStarting` and `TestFinished` methods of the load test plugins are called for all tests executed as part of the load test.

The final assignment of the code in the question can be simplified to `int webTestUserId = e.WebTest.Context.WebTestUserId;`. This applies to both validation rules and to plugins.